# s-nail package version 15 will wipe out old option?

Tags: linux, email

So i recently created a script using s-nail to send mail relay to an external SMTP server
in the script, I simply have s-nail -S smtp="serverip:port" and my destination address
It works, but in the verbose log, it shows the following lines

`s-nail: Obsoletion warning: Use of old-style credentials, which will vanish in v15! Please read the manual section "On URL syntax and credential lookup" s-nail: Obsoletion warning: please don't use *smtp*: assign a smtp:// URL to *mta*!`

Now I did some read and it does not seems complicate. i just need to slightly adjust my script the way it send. But since our environment still does not use smtp auth . so my question is do I need to worry? I mean will s nail actually force you to use the new URL format? the issue with new format is that in the man page, it seems like you will have to provide username and password and can not leave those fields to empty. Otherwise, it fail when I try it.

ANy suggestion?

Or can you use it without any username and password?

NOTE - our test environment does not support username and password auth.

Or ....

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your SMTP doesn't require Auth

```
set v15-compat
set smtp-auth=none
set mta=smtp://yourserver.yourdomain.com:port
```